# Highchart: Flags goes out of stock chart on set extreme

Tags: highcharts

As highchart provides great features of charting, we have incorporated Highchart library in our web application.

As per the requirement we have to display flags on specific datapoints. So I am using `flags` series to achieve the same as mentioned below:

```
   series: [{
      name: 'USD to EUR',
      data: [{
          y: 1,
          x: Date.UTC(2017, 5, 12)
        },
        {
          y: 3,
          x: Date.UTC(2017, 6, 13)
        },
        {
          y: 5,
          x: Date.UTC(2017, 7, 14)
        },
        {
          y: 7,
          x: Date.UTC(2017, 8, 15)
        },
        {
          y: 9,
          x: Date.UTC(2017, 9, 16)
        },
        {
          y: 11,
          x: Date.UTC(2017, 10, 17)
        },
        {
          y: 13,
          x: Date.UTC(2017, 11, 18)
        },
        {
          y: 15,
          x: Date.UTC(2017, 12, 19)
        },
        {
          y: 17,
          x: Date.UTC(2018, 1, 20)
        },
        {
          y: 19,
          x: Date.UTC(2018, 2, 21)
        }
      ],
      id: 'dataseries'

      // the event marker flags
    }, {
      type: 'flags',
      y: -5,
      data: [{
          x: Date.UTC(2017, 5, 12),
          title: ' '
        },
        {
          x: Date.UTC(2017, 6, 13),
          title: ' '
        },
        {
          x: Date.UTC(2017, 7, 14),
          title: ' '
        },
        {
          x: Date.UTC(2017, 8, 15),
          title: ' '
        },
        {
          x: Date.UTC(2017, 9, 16),
          title: ' '
        },
        {
          x: Date.UTC(2017, 10, 17),
          title: ' '
        },
        {
          x: Date.UTC(2017, 11, 18),
          title: ' '
        },
        {
          x: Date.UTC(2017, 12, 19),
          title: ' '
        },
        {
          x: Date.UTC(2018, 1, 20),
          title: ' '
        },
        {
          x: Date.UTC(2018, 2, 21),
          title: ' '
        }
      ]
```

But when series is plotted with flags and when I set extremes on Y-Axis, this symbols goes out of chart as shown in below image:

[image]

Is there any work around to fix this issue ?

Here is the [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/md82wpfk/3/).

Comment: It's look like a highstock [bug](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/8546)

Comment: Yeh. But is there any work around for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Issue reported in Highcharts github, marker as a bug: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/8546

**Workaround:**

```
chart: {
  events: {
    load: function() {
      this.series[1].markerGroup.clip(this.clipRect); // series[1] -> index of flag series
    }
  }
},
```

**Demo:**

https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/md82wpfk/8/